# cURL POST: 400 Invalid content length

Tags: php, post, curl

I am having issues sending POST requests with my cURL script in PHP.

I am trying to make a proxy, essentially, for my own personal use, that will get the web page via the server and display it to me locally.

The URL is found like so: **http://fetch.example.com/http://theurl.com/**

When I post in a form on that page, it will go to the form's ACTION (with the fetch URL in front). I am trying to make it process this POST request using the code below, but anything I POST always brings a 400 Bad Request error.

```
$chpg = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_URL, $_URL);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies/$_COOKIE_FILE.$_DOMAIN.txt");
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies/$_COOKIE_FILE.$_DOMAIN.txt");
if($_POST) {
    $fields = array();
    foreach($_POST as $col => $val) {
        $fields[$col] = urlencode($val);
    }
    print_r($fields);
    curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_POSTDATA, $fields);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems there:

1. `CURLOPT_POSTDATA` should be `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.
2. You're sending the `$fields` *PHP array* as the
   `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. This actually needs to be a string in the
   format `name1=value1&name2=value2&...`.

   To fix these problems, modify your PHP code as follows:

   ```php
   if($_POST) {
       $fields_str = http_build_query($_POST);

       curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
       curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_str);
   }
   ```

   As [Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) pointed out, you can ditch the `foreach` loop and use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead.

Comment: Instead of the foreach loop you could just do `$fields_str=http_build_query($_POST)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Ha, that's brilliant. I didn't realise that existed! Learn something new every day. :)

Comment: Would I need to also use urlencode on the query? It seems I cannot login to Hotmail with this project - it says my email and pass is correct, yet I see the query and it shows fine.

Comment: By default `http_build_query` will URL-encode the values (according to RFC 1738) automatically.

Comment: Odd. Not sure why I can't get into Hotmail with it then - it says it's incorrect. I'll look into it. Thanks! :)

Comment: -1 because array is/was valid curl option there, if array vs string boils down to how data will be encoded: multipart/form-data vs x-www-form-urlencoded. You need first one if You want to send files.

Comment: Reread the question and I've earned that (-). Question was about using `$_POST` params. Answer would not be valid if question was also about `$_FILES`, as `http_build_query` wont handle those. As is, it's simple and correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) & fixed `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

```
$chpg = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_URL, $_URL);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies/$_COOKIE_FILE.$_DOMAIN.txt");
curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies/$_COOKIE_FILE.$_DOMAIN.txt");
if($_POST) {
    curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
    curl_setopt($chpg, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
}
```